# R xml2 tidyverse: How to map values from different levels in xml document?

Tags: r, mapping, xml2

I'm in dire need of some help from some R and XML Pros.

I have a couple of thousand XML files, that I need to convert to R data frames or preferably tibbles. The XML files are kind of messy, as none of the available packages is able to read and convert them "on the fly", so I'm trying to query values using the XML2 package.

Here is a minimal working example, with mock data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2) 

interimxml <- read_xml("<report>
                          <hospital>
                            <hospital_contact>
                              <name>University Hospital Sidney</name>
                              <hospital_id>1234</hospital_id>
                              <location>Sidney</location>
                            </hospital_contact>
                         </hospital>
                         <hospital_departments>
                          <department>
                            <Name>Neurosurgery</Name>
                            <department_key>20010</department_key>
                            <cases_department>
                              <full_stationary>100</full_stationary>
                              <parttime_inpatient>50</parttime_inpatient>
                            </cases_department>
                            <staff>
                              <doctors>
                                <occupancy_doctors>2</occupancy_doctors>
                                <specialist>10</specialist>
                              </doctors>
                              <care>
                                <nurses>10</nurses>
                                <midwives>0</midwives>
                              </care>
                            </staff>
                            <procedures_done>
                              <mandatory_disclosure>
                                <procedure>
                                  <procedure_id> a.10 </procedure_id>
                                  <amount>10</amount>
                                </procedure>
                                <procedure>
                                  <procedure_id> b.15 </procedure_id>
                                  <amount>12</amount>
                                </procedure>
                              </mandatory_disclosure>
                            </procedures_done>
                          </department>
                          <department>
                            <Name>Pediatrics</Name>
                            <department_key>10020</department_key>
                            <cases_department>
                              <full_stationary>
                              140
                              </full_stationary>
                              <parttime_inpatient>
                              40
                              </parttime_inpatient>
                            </cases_department>
                            <staff>
                              <doctors>
                                <occupancy_doctors></occupancy_doctors>
                                <specialist>20</specialist>
                              </doctors>
                              <care>
                                <nurses>20</nurses>
                                <midwives>2</midwives>
                              </care>
                            </staff>
                            <procedures_done>
                              <mandatory_disclosure>
                                <procedure>
                                  <procedure_id> c.14 </procedure_id>
                                  <amount>5</amount>
                                </procedure>
                                <procedure>
                                  <procedure_id> c.19 </procedure_id>
                                  <amount>20</amount>
                                </procedure>
                              </mandatory_disclosure>
                            </procedures_done>
                          </department>
                          <department>
                            <Name>Stroke_Unit</Name>
                            <department_key>12018</department_key>
                            <cases_department>
                              <full_stationary>
                              20
                              </full_stationary>
                            </cases_department>
                            <staff>
                              <doctors>
                                <specialist>20</specialist>
                              </doctors>
                              <care>
                                <nurses>20</nurses>
                                <midwives>0</midwives>
                            </care>
                            </staff>
                            <procedures_done>
                              <mandatory_disclosure>
                                <procedure>
                                  <procedure_id> g.12 </procedure_id>
                                  <amount>20</amount>
                                </procedure>
                                <procedure>
                                  <procedure_id> c.19 </procedure_id>
                                  <amount>20</amount>
                                </procedure>
                              </mandatory_disclosure>
                            </procedures_done>
                          </department>
                          <department>
                            <Name>Intensive_Care</Name>
                            <department_key>19201</department_key>
                            <cases_department>
                              <full_stationary>
                                190
                              </full_stationary>
                            </cases_department>
                            <staff>
                              <doctors>
                                <specialist>20</specialist>
                              </doctors>
                              <care>
                                <nurses>90</nurses>
                              </care>
                            </staff>
                          <procedures_done>
                            <mandatory_disclosure>
                              <noprocedures/>
                            </mandatory_disclosure>
                          </procedures_done>
                         </department>
                          </hospital_departments>
                         </report>")
```

I know how to query values, say for example "department_keys", using the xml_find_all function from the xml2 packages (The xml2 help unfortunately is kind of cryptic). The problem, however, is with the values "nested" in lower levels ("children"?). For example, not all departments report midwives, not all departments have occupancy physicians (i.e. external physicians). This is the case for the department "intensive care", which only employs "specialists". Some departments only have stationary cases, and no "parttime "patients. Then, if I query values, where the is no listing, my values will get messed up. I know that I will have to somehow map these values, but I can't seem to get the XPath right.

Here is what I would like to achieve ( or like to end up with) :

```
hospital_departments <- tribble(
  ~hospital_name,              ~hospital_id, ~department_name, ~department_key, ~full_stationary, ~parttime_inpatient, ~occupancy_doctors,~specialists, ~nurses, ~midwives, 
  "University Hospital Sidney", 1234       , "Neurosurgery"  , "20010"        , 100             , 50                 , 2                 , 10         , 10     , 0, 
  "University Hospital Sidney", 1234       , "Pediatrics"    , "10020"        , 140             , 40                 , NA                , 20         , 20     , 2,
  "University Hospital Sidney", 1234       , "Stroke Unit"   , "12018"        , 20              , NA                 , NA                , 20         , 20     , 0,
  "University Hospital Sidney", 1234       , "Intensive Care", "19201"        , 190             , NA                 , NA                , 20         , 90     , NA
)

hospital_departments 

department_procedures <- tribble(~hospital_name,              ~hospital_key, ~department_key, ~procedure_id, ~amount, 
                            "University Hospital Sidney", 1234        , 20010          , "a.10", 10,
                            "University Hospital Sidney", 1234        , 20010          , "b.15", 12,
                            "University Hospital Sidney", 1234        , 10020          , "c.14", 5,
                            "University Hospital Sidney", 1234        , 10020          , "c.19", 20,
                            "University Hospital Sidney", 1234        , 12018          , "g.12", 20, 
                            "University Hospital Sidney", 1234        , 12018          , "c.19", 20 # Same procedure is done by intensive care and pediatrics
  
)

department_procedures
```

I would like to have a tibble with all the department details with correct NAs and a separate tibble with all the procedures done (which might be a couple of hundred, which all differ across departments). Once I have these two tibble I know how to use tidyverse (which is my main package for data processing) to further proceed with the data.

Any hint or help I highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the code you tried look like? In what way did your xpath attempt not work?

Comment: For the procedures I can use your approach, because the values are all on the same level (siblings, I hope this is the correct terminology). But for the "department characteristics" this no longer "works", since the values I'm interested in are spread across different branches. I read a lot on https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp on XML XPath syntax, but I'm still (very) lost.

Answer (score 2):

This is common problem with variable number of child nodes.  The key to solving these problems is processing the file in chucks of consistent data groupings.  In this case, 3 parts, the hospital information, the department information and procedures.

Since the number of procedures per department varies, the method is to find all of the department nodes and then loop through each node (see lapply loop in code). Extract the procedures and attached the department ID.  This will create a list of data frames, one for each department.  Use `bind_rows()` to merge the data.frames together for the final table.

This code with some modification can be enclosed in loop (or two) to cycle through your list of files.

```
library(dplyr)
library(xml2) 

#get hospitalInfo
hospitalInfo <- interimxml %>% xml_find_all(".//hospital_contact") 
hospInfo <- data.frame(t(xml_children(hospitalInfo) %>% xml_text())) 
names(hospInfo) <- xml_children(hospitalInfo) %>% xml_name()

#get information on departments
depts <- interimxml %>% xml_find_all(".//department") 

#since you are interested in specific information and values are nest, 
#sometime it is just easier to brute force collecting the information
   department_name <- depts %>% xml_find_first(".//Name") %>% xml_text()
   department_key <- depts %>% xml_find_first(".//department_key") %>% xml_integer()
   full_stationary <- depts %>% xml_find_first(".//full_stationary") %>% xml_integer()
   parttime_inpatient <- depts %>% xml_find_first(".//parttime_inpatient") %>% xml_integer()
   occupancy_doctors <- depts %>% xml_find_first(".//occupancy_doctors") %>% xml_integer()
   specialists <- depts %>% xml_find_first(".//specialists") %>% xml_integer()
   nurses <- depts %>% xml_find_first(".//nurses") %>% xml_integer()
   midwives <- depts %>% xml_find_first(".//midwives") %>% xml_integer()

hospital_departments<-data.frame(department_name, department_key, full_stationary, parttime_inpatient, occupancy_doctors,
                                 specialists, nurses, midwives)
hospital_departments <- cbind(hospInfo, hospital_departments)

#since the number of procedures vary from 0 to more than 1 a different procedure is required
tempdfs <-lapply(depts, function(node) {
   department_key <- node %>% xml_find_first(".//department_key") %>% xml_integer()
   procedure_id <- node %>% xml_find_all(".//procedure_id") %>% xml_text()
   amount <- node %>% xml_find_all(".//amount") %>% xml_integer()
   
   #pack into a dataframe
   #cleck to see if a procedure is performed
   if (length(procedure_id) >0) {
   data.frame(department_key, procedure_id, amount)
   } else {
      #handle cases with no procedures
      data.frame(department_key)
   }   
})

department_procedures <- cbind(hospInfo, bind_rows(tempdfs))

print(hospital_departments)
print(department_procedures)
```

Comment: @minimouse, Did this solution work for you?